# In Perl, why is my regex replace failing when the pattern contains a parenthesized addition?

Tags: regex, perl

I am stumbling over a very basic perl sed operation. Cannot figure out where is the problem. at some point in my program, I have a string that has the following line:

```
my $line = "(l_extendedprice*(THISISREPLACED)*(1+l_tax))";

my $substitute = "(1+l_tax)";

if($line=~ /$substitute/){
$line =~ s/$substitute/matched/;
}
```

Observed output:

```
(l_extendedprice*(THISISREPLACED)*(1+l_tax))
```

Desired output:

```
(l_extendedprice*(THISISREPLACED)*(matched))
```

**Update:**

The value of $line and `$substitute` are generated from a part of the code. So, is there way to deal with `*`, `+` without breaking `$substitute` into pieces?

Comment: What the heck is a "perl sed operation"?

Comment: That code doesn't produce any output.

Comment: @SinanÜnür "In mathematics, summation (capital Greek sigma symbol: ∑) is the addition of a sequence of numbers" says Wikipedia. I already edited the title once.

Comment: For reference, in English, we have [summation](http://www.bennetyee.org/http_webster.cgi?summation&method=exact):  *The act of summing, or forming a sum*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match and substitution operators expect a regex pattern.

The regex pattern `(1+l_tax)` does not match the string `(1+l_tax)`.

The regex pattern `\(1\+l_tax\)` is one that only matches the string `(1+l_tax)`.

You can get a pattern that matches a specific string by using `quotemeta` on that string.

```
my $substr_re = quotemeta($substr);
if ($string =~ /$substr_re/) { ... }
```

You can use `\Q..\E` in a regex-expecting operator as a shortcut for `quotemeta`.

```
if ($string =~ /\Q$substr\E/) { ... }
```

The `\E` is optional if it's at the end of the literal.

```
if ($string =~ /\Q$substr/) { ... }
```

---

In your case, you need to start by fixing `$substitute` to be the string you want to substitute.

```
my $substitute = "1+l_tax";
```

Then, you can use what I showed earlier to match and substitute it.

```
if ($line =~ /\Q$substitute/) {
    $line =~ s/\Q$substitute/matched/;
}
```

That simplifies to the following:

```
$line =~ s/\Q$substitute/matched/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
my $substitute = "(1+l_tax)";
```

which you then use in a regex match:

```
if($line=~ /$substitute/){
```

But, of course, `1+` means "*match one or more 1's in the string*". Also, `(...)` means capture. So, you need to escape those characters which have special meaning in a regex pattern.

Also, you do not need to match first to replace:

```
my $line = "(l_extendedprice*(THISISREPLACED)*(1+l_tax))";

my $substitute = "(1+l_tax)";

$line =~ s/\Q$substitute/matched/;
```

Note `$line =~ s/.../.../` instead of `$line = s/.../.../`. The latter (which is how you have it in your code) would replace the value in `$line` with the result of `$_ =~ s/.../.../`.

Comment: @tt_pre  Just in case: note that "_the result of `$_ =~ s/.../.../`"_ is the number of substitutions made.  Not the new string.  (From v5.14 you _can_ do `$new_var = $var =~ s/.../.../r` (note `/r`), where `$var` is unchanged and the new string after substitutions is retured and assigned to `$new_var`)

Answer (score -2):

escape the + sign.

```
echo "(l_extendedprice*(THISISREPLACED)*(1+l_tax))" |perl -npe 's/1\+l_tax/matched/'

(l_extendedprice*(THISISREPLACED)*(matched))
```